# Generating entity with jhipster 4.14.5 doesnt work

Tags: jhipster

When i'm trying to generate entity or controller or service with jhipster 4.14.5 for a microservice application it doesnt work.

The CLI do not print any errors. It stopped and doesnt go further. See picture.

How can i generate it?[image]

Comment: I have 4.14.1 version, it works ok. Maybe something with permissions. Can you run cmd->jhipster under admin user?

Comment: when i use the latest jhipster version 5.0.2 it's works. But my project are all built with 4.14.1